# C#. Action, отдельный поток и зависание интерфейса

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Не уверен, что кто-то напрямую с подобным сталкивался, но, возможно, кто-нибудь сможет подсказать методы отладки и поиска причины ошибки.

Есть приложение уровня предприятия. Получает данные с SQL-сервера (хранимых процедур) по ним строит отчеты в соответствии с макетами (используется DevExpress 17.2.7, как репортинг так и контролы интерфейса). 
Версия Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2012, WinForms, разработка идет под ОС Windows 10.

*Данные получаются следующим образом:*

- от клиента - запрос к dll с бизнес-логикой "BLL" (с передачей в
  методы BLL объектов кода клиента, некоторые из них, при этом,
  привязаны к интерфейсу на форме)
- BLL по этим объектам формирует объект DataQuery содержащий запрос, параметры, таймаут, уровень изоляции и т.д.
- BLL через клиент WCF (насколько понимаю исп. на низком уровне обращения к COM) отправляет этот объект на сервер - хостинг службы WCF.
- Служба вызывает dll с уровем данных "DALC", обрабатывающий запрос и возвращающий объект DataReturn (DataSet с данными, статус завершения операции, ошибки получения данных, если таковые были)
- Дальше все происходит в обратном порядке, результат возвращается клиенту, по DataSet формируется отчет в соотв. с макетами DevExpress
- На этом обработка данных заканчивается (далее должен открыться вьювер DevExpress для просмотра файла этого отчета)

*Но получается следующее:*

- "Прямой" вызов из основного потока - все отрабатывает как задумано
- Любой вызов как Action через Task, Thread (пробовал исп. и из под backgroundWorker и без Action, просто отдельным потомком метод) - ведет к тому, что на 10 или 20 отчете вьювер открывается и виснет (хотя приложение не определяется как зависшее). Подключение отладчика с ассемблером указывает на вызов из ntdll.dll и инструкцию ret, причем попытка сделать "шаг вперед" вызывает ошибку типа "адрес не существует"
- Попытки (а точнее - штатная задумка) вызывать форму ожидания, куда параметром передается делегат\Action\Task или т.п. (все перебрал, что в пункте выше) с логикой получения данных, прогресс-баром и счетчиком-таймером времени - перманентно приводит к тому, что в какой-то момент (причем, по моим наблюдениям, это как-то связанно со временем построения отчета... например, отчет строится 1 мин. 40 сек. на 4-5 отчете, другой 14 сек. - на 15-16 отчете) все таймеры летят, контролы окна, типа кнопки "отмена", замораживаются и т.д. После такого "висения" в течении 3-5 минут, внезапно, все отрабатывает и отчет открывается. Если подключить отладчик с ассемблером, тоже самое, указание на ntdll.dll и ret и, если не ошибаюсь, на WaitForSingleObjectEx (если не ошибаюсь, ожидание обратного вызова, вероятно из делегата). "Шаг вперед" под ассемблером - все дорабатывает дальше штатно.

Происходит это, как водится, не под Visual Studio, а при запуске через exe-файл. 
Отчасти "на мое счастье" - такое происходит и при запуске debug сборки, поэтому удалось приаттачиться с кодом и проверить - вся логика в "теле" делегата исполняется вовремя и "штатно", данные возвращаются как надо, без задержек, ошибок в программе не возникает, WCF не отваливается. Ощущение такое, что сбои и "заморозка UI" происходят на системном уровне. Ко всему прочему - "ошибка накапливается" с числом вызовов и как-то зависят еще от времени работы (построения отчета).
WCF сконфигурирован так (если, конечно, дело в нем): tcp/ip, буферизация, InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false.
И, как уже говорил, выполнение логики в основном потоке приложения не приводит ни к чему, стоит использовать что угодно для вызова нового потока (делегат\Action с Task, backgroundWorker, Thread) - фейл. Напрямую обращений к интерфейсу в потоке - нет.
Не сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобным или нет ли у кого-нибудь идей, как все-таки можно "продебажить" этот момент и понять, в чем все-таки проблема?

Comment: Без конкретного примера для воспроизведения проблемы - найти причину почти нереально. Судя по описанию, вы что-то тяжелое выполняете в UI потоке (ну или блокируете его на время фоновой операции). Попробуйте прицепится отладчиком (Visual Studio), переключить в окне threads на основной поток, и глянуть стек трейс. К релизной сборке тоже можно прицепить студию, кстати, даже с кодом - только номера строк чуть съедут.

Comment: Мои предположения: 1. Где-то всё же есть обращения к gui из дополнительного потока. 2. Где-то используются локальные объекты, которые удаляет сборщик мусора, после чего возникают проблемы. Сужу об этом по долгому времени построения отчётов - GC не раз может сработать. 3. Где-то не освобождаются ресурсы: не используются using/Dispose. В итоге возникает нехватка хендлов ОС. Всё это чисто умозрительные предположения.